# Map orientation

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I have got this map that can lead me to a underwater temple. That's nice, but I see only this:

[image]

The red lines and stuff are only for effect.

Is the map always orientated by the X and Z coordinates? if not, how can I locate the direction of the mapped area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maps are always orientated X left/right & Z up/down. Positive and Negative as assumed. No reason to change them and alter the standard for one particular map.

Also you can move around a bit and track where your dot is moving to tell what means what.

Comment: one thing to note is that moving and tracking the dot doesn't work if the dot is in the corner like in the OP's image